# RenderTexture does not clear buffer

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

I'm trying to implement the Pixel-perfect collision testing in cocos2d-JavaScript.

I can not get pixel buffer cleared. I don't know why.

I do:

```
var winSize = cc.director.getWinSize();

var rend = new cc.RenderTexture( winSize.width , winSize.height, cc.Texture2D.PIXEL_FORMAT_RGBA8888);
var pixels = new Uint8Array(4 * ~~numPixels);   

rend.beginWithClear( 0, 0, 0, 255); 

gl.readPixels(x, y, w, h, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

rend.end();

for(var i = 0; i < ~~numPixels; i+= 1)
{
    var rb = pixels[4*i + 0];
    var gb = pixels[4*i + 1];
    DEBUG(LEVEL_DEBUG, "PP - collision test", "i=%s; rb=%s; gb=%s;", ""+i, ""+rb, ""+gb);
}
```

Yes, I do not even any drawing. Just trying to clear `renderTexture`, `readPixels` and check them if it was cleared. It was not.

I even tried first to fill the array pixels with some known values, checked it - yes it was there. After `readPixels` there are different values but not clear...
 What is wrong? Can somebody help?
I also tried `rend.cleanup();` 
I tried split `beginWithClear` to separate `clear()` and `begin()` ... same result.
I tried `rend.clearRect` ... `rend.setClearColor` ... nothing helped.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/how-to-get-single-pixel-of-sprite-with-cocos2djs-and-cocosbuilder/7250/5